# Passing parameters to custom Conditons

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to do something as the following to conditional load a bean:

```
@Conditional(OnAuthoritieCondition.class, "SOME_INPUT_STRING")
```

However when I try to implement this I get the following:

```
public class OnAuthoritieCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now my question is how can I implement a custom condition that takes parameters or is there a better way to do what I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create your custom annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Conditional(value = CustomCondition.class)
public @interface ConditionalController {

  String condition();

}
```

your custom condition

```
public class CustomCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
      Map<String, Object> attributes = metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(ConditionalController.class.getName());
      String condition = (String) attributes.get("condition");
      return "GO".equalsIgnoreCase(condition);
    }

}
```

use it like

```
@ConditionalController(condition = "GO")
```